# Created meta tags (with Javascript) does not show when copy link

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I might have a problem, maybe actually two. First of all, I have to tell you that I am **restricted to use only Javascript** for this solution. So I am creating meta tags with javascript. When I call my site, the meta tags will be all filled as expected. But now my problem is here, when I try to copy the link and share it on `web.whatsapp.com` or `facebook` for example, all I see are the default meta tags. I get it, when they (whatsapp or facebook) parse my site, they don't execute javascript, so they only use the default meta tags given. But is there any solution to still get the javascript generated meta tags?

Comment: So you have pointed out whatsapp/facebook don't execute javascript.... So if it isn't executed then how would it be possible to use javascript to fill in the meta tags.... Javascript would need to be executed for you to use a javascript solution.... I think you might be answering your own question within your question.

Comment: @NewToJS I might, sometimes the internet does some magic, so I hoped this time too :) but thank you for the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

No.

If the Facebook or Whatsapp's clients don't execute JavaScript on your DOM before searching for meta elements, then you can't make them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed **only use JavaScript on frontend** side **you can't** achieve this functionality of sharing meta tags.

*but*

Technically **you can do it** only using JavaScript, but you **must use JavaScript on the backend (Node.js)** to generate this meta tags. Your assumptions from question didn't mention that you can't use JavaScript on the backend.